# if <string> not in <someList>.name

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting

I have a list, containing some strings.
Before adding a new string, I check if this string is already in the list, otherwise, add it:

```
myList = []
....
name = "myName"
...
if name not in myList:
    myList.append(name)
```

Problem is, is need to store more information, not only the name.
So i created a class.

```
myList = []
myListEntry = someClass()
....
myListEntry.name = "myName"
...
```

I want myList now to contain objects instead of strings.
But, this way my
    if myListEntry.name not in myList:
no longer works.
myList is a list of objects, so the if-statement will always return True, resulting in multiple entries for the same name.

I can think of an C-like workaround, using a oldschool for-loop and a boolean flag.
However, whats the pythonic way to solve this issue?

Comment: So why not use a set instead? If your objects must be unique a set is a better way to track what is already added. Or is order important too?

Answer (score 1):

So if you want object in a list with unique Names only, you have to overwrite the `__eq__()` method of your class.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, A):
            return self.name == other.name

a = A("test", 2)
b = A("test", 3)
c = A("test2", 4)

listA = []

listA.append(a)

if b not in listA:
    listA.append(b)

if c not in listA:
    listA.append(c)

print listA
```

This way you can use your `if _ not in List`

Comment: Here a small guide how to overwrite comparison operation: http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/32837.html

Answer (score 1):

The pythonic way is to use a set to track unique objects. If your set is specialised (values are unique by a specific attribute) then you have two options:

- If two objects are considered equal, in all contexts, because their name is equal (and the extra information doesn't change this), then give your objects [`object.__hash__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) and [`object.__eq__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) methods, and simply add the object to a set.
- If your objects are only equal in this context, you can wrap the set and extract the right attribute in a custom [`object.__contains__()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__), or you could wrap a list object and track names already seen in a separate set when appending.

The latter approach could look something like this:

```
class MyUniqueInfo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._values = []
        self._seen = set()
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if hasattr(self._values, attr):
            return getattr(self._values, attr)
        raise AttributeError(attr)
    def append(self, value):
        if value.name in self._seen:
            return
        self._values.append(value)
        self._seen.add(value.name)
```

This has the added advantage that it maintains the order in which items where appended first.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your `list_of_objects` have an attribute of `name`

something like this maybe?

```
class Test1:
    name = "John"
class Test2:
    name = "Johnny"
class Test3:
    name = "Jill"

test_object1 = Test1()
test_object2 = Test2()
test_object3 = Test3()

new_list = []

list_of_objects  =[test_object2,test_object3]
if test_object1.name not in [object.name for object in list_of_objects]:
    new_list.append(test_object1)

print(new_list)
```